# Jenkins workflow stash/unstash zip file

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I am stashing/unstashing a single zip file and the console output when I do so says 
Stashed 411 file(s)
I suppose there are 411 files inside the zip file and this is stored? So stashing unarchives the file before doing so?
In any case, the problem is that unstashing this is taking an inordinate amount of time, approx. 4 minutes over my last ten runs since I've been doing this unstashing. I am actually unstashing to the same node, which needs to happen as possibly it's a different node since I am just giving a label. The zip file is only 14MB. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there is a mistake in your `includes`/`excludes` and you are actually stashing 411 files rather than just one.